# How to resolve Typescript "Object is possibly undefined" warning when sorting objects by property value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, undefined

I have an array of objects that I'm sorting by the value of one of the properties. The sort is working correctly but I'm getting a Typescript warning that "Object is possibly 'undefined'"

How do I check for undefined values on name to resolve this warning?

```
myItems.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name  ? 1 : -1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Typescript is telling you there is a bug in your code. The type of your array apparently is something like:

```
({ name: string } | undefined)[]
```

That means that when you iterate over that array, you need to handle the case where the item is `undefined`, otherwise `(undefined).name` will throw a runtime error.

---

The easiest way to fix this is probably to filter your array so it no longer includes any undefined values:

```
interface MyItem { name: string }

const myItems: (MyItem | undefined)[] = [
  { name: 'c' },
  { name: 'b' },
  undefined,
  { name: 'a' },
]

myItems
  .filter((item): item is MyItem => !!item)
  .sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name  ? 1 : -1));
```

This uses a filter function that is also a [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). After it runs, the returned array will be of type `MyItem[]`, and then your sort can run correctly knowing that all items have a value.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=3&pln=17&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CSkC2yDeyIcOEAXMgM5hSgDmyAvgFDMID2I1yOWulFABQZsEPAB9kAVxAATCDFARZASgDaAXWQBeZGubICREuWQByBGaYAaA0eKkKZgEZXGtwzPmKQyj-ZMnODdbDVYOLjAqdihIWR0ePjFKOwA6RQAbSChBQWBcFQp8sWRgSjQkvG0APmQAQjrinBU0yhiwXLhrZGcVHVrBOFSHFFrnYZNDAH5kAEZkCgBaWZUVAG5wzjaMiFSM9jpBNtjlFoB6ACoL5jV8OwAiEfuKe7h75ncCB6eX53fPu6GR4mZ7Ie4If5aZgXM5AA)