# typescript error: Object is possibly 'undefined'. when sorting array based on the contents of object map

Tags: typescript

the error is currEmot is possibly undefined. I'm confused why that is occurring because the for loop is guaranteed to loop through the emotionsObject and add objects to the map.

```
let emotionsObject = [
{
    size: 80,
    background: 'rgb(67, 0, 128)',
    width: .5,
    emoji: "",
    name: 'joy'
},
{
    size: 34,
    background: 'rgb(0, 45, 172)',
    width: .35,
    emoji: "",
    name: 'sadness',
},
{
    size: 50,
    background: 'rgb(172, 6, 0)',
    width: .15,
    emoji: "",
    name: 'anger',
},
];
type T_Emotion = typeof emotionsObject[0] 
let currEmot = new Map<string, T_Emotion>(null!);
let emotOrder: string[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < emotionsObject.length; i++) {
   let id = uuid_v4();
   emotOrder.push(id)
   currEmot.set(id, emotionsObject[I]);
}

emotOrder.sort((a: string, b: string):number => currEmot.get(b).width - currEmot.get(a).width);
```

I have tried these other versions to prevent this error.

```
emotOrder.sort((a: string, b: string):number => currEmot?.get(b)?.width - currEmot?.get(a)?.width);
emotOrder.sort((a: string, b: string):number => currEmot.get(b).width as number - currEmot.get(a).width as number);
```

Comment: `null!` ...huh?

Comment: Where does the `I` come from all of the sudden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bang operator `!` to tell typescript that there will be no situation where object is not found

```
currEmot.get(b)!.width - currEmot.get(a)!.width
```

Comment: this operator gives another warning `ESLint: Forbidden non-null assertion. (@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion)`

Comment: you could use `?.` operator instead, but I believe turning on "non-null assertion" rule in eslint is not right

Comment: `?.` operator gives `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.` 

This answer helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942654/how-to-resolve-typescript-object-is-possibly-undefined-warning-when-sorting-ob

Answer (score 1):

You need to creact `Interface` and set it to your object

```
interface IEmotions {
  size: number
  background: string
  width: number
  emoji: string
  name: string
}
```

Please keep in mind if any `key` could be undefined, you need to add `?` to your `key` , for example: `size?: number`

```
let emotionsObject: (IEmotions | undefined)[] = [
 {
    size: 80,
    background: 'rgb(67, 0, 128)',
    width: .5,
    emoji: "",
    name: 'joy'
 }, 
 {
    size: 34,
    background: 'rgb(0, 45, 172)',
    width: .35,
    emoji: "",
    name: 'sadness',
 }
];
```